# How to pipe/redirect from a program that outputs multiple values into a program that accepts just one value, to be executed for all outputs once each

Tags: shell, pipe

I am trying to process IP addresses from *traceroute*,which writes to a file called *td* on disk,after which I do a

`grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]' td | uniq`

to get the list of unique IP addresses. Next i can get the geolocation data for the address by

`lynx -dump http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=8.8.8.8`

But now how do I feed the multiple outputs of the first into the second without needing to write to another file on the disk.

As an aside I was wondering if i could remove the file td completely and pipe *traceroute* output directly to *grep* somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you use a shell `for` loop?

```
for i in $(cat td)
do
  lynx -dump http:/...${i}
done
```

You can replace `$(cat td)` with `$(traceroute <options> | grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]' | uniq)` to avoid the intermediate file `td`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use command substitution and a `for` loop as:

```
for ip in $(grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]*[0-9]*[0-9]' td | sort -u); do lynx -dump http://api.hostip.info/get_html.php?ip=$ip; done
```

Also note that your `uniq` might not work as it expects the input to be sorted. Instead you can use a `sort -u`.

Comment: Sorting would change the sequence of `traceroute` ip address, which i want to preserve. Further, `uniq` needs duplicate lines to be adjacent, and in the traceroute data, it is always adjacent, so its working for now. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: @NitinAb: Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most.